# How to generate <sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> format bagfile

Tags: ros, rosbag, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, vlp16

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have some pcap files that were collected in velodyne VLP16, how do I convert this pcap file to a bagfile in the sensor_msgs::pointcloud2 format ?
I've tried it

`rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _model:=VLP16 _pcap:=/your/pcap/path/data.pcap _read_once:=true`

`rosrun rosbag record -O out.bag /velodyne_packets`.

But the bag file generated is of type velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan, my program needs sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 type data.
This is a piece of code from my project

`subLaserCloud = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("TOPICS", 1, &ImageProjection::cloudHandler, this);`

Hope to get a reply soon, and thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330587/how-to-generate-%3Csensor_msgs::pointcloud2%3E-format-bagfile/) by [3fmeow](https://answers.ros.org/users/44779/3fmeow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well according to the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_driver?distro=kinetic) velodyne_node captures Velodyne 3D LIDAR data and publishes it in raw form. This uses the same device driver class as velodyne_driver/DriverNodelet. 
I guess you have been looking at this [answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/213080/convert-raw-velodyne-vlp16-pcap-to-bagfile/). Looks like the next thing yo need to do is convert the  velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan into sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 by using the `CloudNodelet` from [velodyne_pointcloud](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_pointcloud) or the `cloud_node`.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [3fmeow](https://answers.ros.org/users/44779/3fmeow/) on 2019-08-13**:
Yes, thank you very much for your advice.
Here is my current operation process：

```
roscore
rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _model:=VLP16 _pcap:=my.pcap _read_once:=true
rosrun nodelet nodelet standalone velodyne_pointcloud/CloudNodelet _calibration:=VLP-16.yaml
```

Then began to run my program, now I can finally see the images in the rviz.
And I have a new problem, I want to save the data of PointCloud2. After executing the above three steps, I run the following command in a new terminal：

`rosrun rosbag record -O out1.bag /velodyne_points`

Terminal print

```
[ WARN] [1565691355.513475857]: /use_sim_time set to true and no clock published.  Still waiting for valid time...
```

How can I solve this problem. Once again thank you.  : )

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-08-13**:
Im glad it helped. In addition, it is a common practice that if you have a new problem you should create a new question to keep problem tracking organized. As for your new problem, refer to this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/325667/how-to-set-use_sim_time/). As you can see you can set the `/use_sim_time` parameter to true/false like this:

```
rosparam set use_sim_time true
```

**Comment by [3fmeow](https://answers.ros.org/users/44779/3fmeow/) on 2019-08-13**:
thank you very much